# Can't get values from returned code of webservice

Tags: php, arrays, json

I can't get the value of specific "fields" back into PHP when I use a rest API of a system. 
The error messages say:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in.

```
$response = file_get_contents('https:/....');
echo $response->Ticket['Owner'];
echo $response->Ticket->Owner;
echo $response['Owner'];
```

```
{"Ticket":[{"Owner":"root@localhost","EscalationTime":0,"Age":17628,"ChangeBy":7}]}"
```

is part of what I get returned. Now I would like to store e.g. "Owner" into a php variable....

But using `$response->Owner` or `$response->Ticket->Owner`

I get the property of non-object error

Comment: Have you tried **decoding** that JSON string first?

Comment: When I decode, the print_r result looks like this:Array ( [Ticket] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [ArchiveFlag] => n [EscalationTime] => 0 [Age] => 19087 [TicketID] => 3 [UnlockTimeout] => 1565776558 [Changed] => 2019-08-14 09:55:58 [LockID] => 1 [CustomerID] => [TypeID] => 1 [ResponsibleID] => 1 [EscalationResponseTime] => 0 [RealTillTimeNotUsed] => 0 [OwnerID] => 1 [PriorityID] => 3 [QueueID] => 2 [Owner] => root@localhost

Comment: Then you have to access it as Array, not Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into this:

```
$obj = '{"Ticket":[{"Owner":"root@localhost","EscalationTime":0,"Age":17628,"ChangeBy":7}]}';  
// This is what you get from your rest API

$arr = json_decode($obj);  // decode the JSON string

print_r($arr);
```

**Output will be:**

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Ticket] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Owner] => root@localhost
                    [EscalationTime] => 0
                    [Age] => 17628
                    [ChangeBy] => 7
                )

        )

)
```

So you can access the data like:

```
echo $arr->Ticket[0]->Owner;
```

**Out will be:**
root@localhost

[Php fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e5bc3564b6f9bb5009c248285a6c81be19ebf7dd)

Answer (score 0):

After decoding use this:

```
echo $response["Ticket"][0]['Owner'];
```